# How to integrate Icon in each row of a grid table?

Tags: sapui5

I would like to have a delete icon in a label of a column of `sap.ui.table.TreeTable`, to prevent an extra column for such.

[image: here]

I would like to put the icon right of the description, associated with an `onPress` Event to delete this row.

I tried to put the icon within the `<t:template>` aggregation. Would this be possible? Corresponding part of code of XML-view is as follows:

```
<t:TreeTable id="tree">
    <t:columns>
        <t:Column>
            <t:label>
                <Label text="{i18n>TREE_NAME_LABEL}"/>
            </t:label>
            <t:template>
                <Label text="{TREE_DESCRIPTION}" />
            </t:template>
        </t:Column>
    </t:columns>
</t:TreeTable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 1.45, we can assign actions for each row declaratively via the table's aggregation `rowActionTemplate`. Currently, the following action types are available:

- `"Delete"`
- `"Navigation"`
- `"Custom"` with e.g. a custom `icon` and a custom `text` in the assigned `RowActionItem`.

In your case, it would be something like this:

```xml
<table:TreeTable xmlns:table="sap.ui.table" id="tree" rowActionCount="1">
  <table:columns>
    <!-- ... -->
  </table:columns>
  <table:rowActionTemplate>
    <table:RowAction>
      <table:RowActionItem
        type="Delelte"
        press=".onDelete"
      />
    </table:RowAction>
  </table:rowActionTemplate>
</table:TreeTable>
```

[image: SAPUI5 sap.ui.table.Table RowAction Delete]

### Note

- **Ensure to set the table's property `rowActionCount`** which is required to render a certain number of actions initially without the user having to click on a <kbd>…</kbd> button.

  > | Name | Default value | Description |
  > | --- | --- | --- |
  > | `rowActionCount` | `0` | Number of row actions made visible which determines the width of the row action column. The values `0`, `1` and `2` are possible. |
- The row action template needs to be reassigned every time its property or aggregation has changed.

  > | Name | Cardinality | Type | Description |
  > | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  > | `rowActionTemplate` | 0..1 | [sap.ui.table.RowAction](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.table.RowAction) | [...] Each time the template's properties or aggregations are changed, **the template has to be applied again** via `setRowActionTemplate` [...]. |

---

- [Demo Kit sample: Table - Row Action](https://sdk.openui5.org/entity/sap.ui.table.Table/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.RowAction)
- [API reference: `sap.ui.table.RowAction`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.table.RowAction)
- [API reference: `sap.ui.table.RowActionItem`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.table.RowActionItem)
- [API reference: `sap.ui.table.Table`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.table.Table)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @boghyon!
Adding your XML code does not change my view, how can the actions being visible and  how can a "delete" begin triggered at all? (You mentioned there will be no visible button, and I cannot see any in your stated example on ui5.sap.com.)
So how can an user trigger a "delete" by himself? I am using UI5 version 1.52.6

Comment: Hi @Pille, I think there is a misunderstanding. If you add `rowActionTemplate` with its `RowAction` etc, then your view should display the appropriate buttons (unless the `rowActionCount` was lower than the number of assigned RowActionItems, then a button with three dots are displayed). Here is the same example but with version 1.52.6: https://ui5.sap.com/1.52.6/#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.RowAction/preview

Comment: Yep you are right. My fault: I forgot to add the property "rowActionCount" in the TreeTable. Was about to delete my comment, you are so fast :-) 
BTW: Any chance to get a "sap-icon/delete" instead of this generated icon like (this big "X")?

Comment: @Pille You can change the icon with the `icon` property from the [RowActionItem](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.RowActionItem/controlProperties). --> `icon="sap-icon://delete"`