# RowActionItem will not be shown

Tags: sapui5

I have a sap.ui.table and I need a navigation for each row.
But for some reason the RowActionItem is not showing.

Anyone have any ideas or spot a bug?

XML:

```
<table:Table rows="{path: 'MyModel>/Trains'}" selectionMode="Single" visibleRowCount="20"
            ariaLabelledBy="title">
            
<!-- ROW ACTION-->
            <table:rowActionTemplate>
                <table:RowAction>
                    <table:RowActionItem type="Navigation" press="doSomething" />
                </table:RowAction>
            </table:rowActionTemplate>


            <table:columns>
                <table:Column showSortMenuEntry="true" sortProperty="ExternalTrainNumber"
                    filterProperty="ExternalTrainNumber">
                    <Label text="Zugnummer" />
                    <table:template>
                        <ObjectIdentifier title="{MyModel>ExternalTrainNumber}"
                            text="{MyModel>TrainDirectionName}" />
                    </table:template>
                </table:Column>
                <table:Column showSortMenuEntry="true" sortProperty="RailwayStationFromName"
                    filterProperty="RailwayStationFromName">
                    <Label text="Von" />
                    <table:template>
                        <Text text="{MyModel>RailwayStationFromName}" wrapping="false" />
                    </table:template>
                </table:Column>
                <table:Column showSortMenuEntry="true" sortProperty="RailwayStationToName"
                    filterProperty="RailwayStationToName">
                    <Label text="Nach" />
                    <table:template>
                        <Text text="{MyModel>RailwayStationToName}" wrapping="false" />
                    </table:template>
                </table:Column>
            </table:columns>
        </table:Table>
```

Comment: You're missing `rowActionCount="1"` in the `table:Table` control. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49362089/5846045